# How to get each value of index using nested foreach loop and save to database php

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm doing a online examination and I want to get the examinee answer and save to database. Now, all my question and examinee answer are stored in array using a input type text with the name of **name=question[ ]** and input type checkbox **name="checker[questionID]"**. This is the sample result.

> Question ID : Array ( [ 0 ] => 131 [ 1 ] => 132 [ 2 ] => 133 [ 3 ] => 130 )

and

> Answer ID : Array ( [131] => 330 [132] => 336 [133] => 339 [130] => 328 )

Now I want to save that value to my database like this:
[image]

Here's my php code and its not working :

```
$selected = $_POST["checker"];
$quest_id = $_POST["question"];

foreach ($quest_id as $key => $q_id) {
 foreach ($selected as $key => $a_id) {
   $get_ans = mysqli_query($connections, "INSERT INTO taker_answer VALUES('','$q_id','$a_id')");
 }
}
```

Please help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$_POST["question"]` array at all. Since your `$_POST["checker"]` has the question ID as keys, you can simply do the following:

```
$selected = $_POST["checker"];

foreach ($selected as $key => $a_id) {
   $get_ans = mysqli_query($connections, "INSERT INTO taker_answer VALUES('','$key','$a_id')");
}
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are vulnerable to SQLIA please make use of prepared statement of either mysqli or PDO.

Now, for your code, you don't need second loop as I think. You just pick answer form the index of array like below

```
$selected = $_POST["checker"];
$quest_id = $_POST["question"];
// here $key hold the value of index  (hold the key if it's associated array)
// and you can get corresponding value of selected answer by $selected[$key] as $key keep changing its value inside loop
foreach ($quest_id as $key => $q_id) {
    $get_ans = mysqli_query($connections, "INSERT INTO taker_answer VALUES('',$q_id,$selected[$key])");
}
```